# Handling long blocking API calls in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, background, cqrs, mediatr

I'm building an API that will handle http calls that perform much work immediately.

For example, in one controller, there is an action (`Post` request) that will take data in the body, and perform some processing that should be done immediately, but will last for about 1 to 2 minutes.

I'm using CQRS, with Mediatr, and inside this post request, I call a command to handle the processing.

Taking this into consideration, I want the post request to launch the command, then return an Ok to the user though the command is still running in the background. The user will be notified via email once everything is done.

Does someone know any best practice to accomplish this?

Though I'm using MediatR, sending the request to the handler, the call is not executed in parallel.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> RequestReports([FromBody] ReportsIntent reportsIntent)
{
     await _mediator.Send(new GetEndOfWeekReports.Command(companyId, clientId, reportsIntent));
     return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does someone know any best practice to accomplish this?

[Yes](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html) (as described on my blog).

You need what I call the "basic distributed architecture". Specifically, you need at least:

1. A durable queue. "Durable" here means "on disk; not in-memory".
2. A backend processor.

So the web api will serialize all the necessary data from the request into a queue message and place that on the queue, and then return to the client.

Then a backend processor retrieves work from that queue and does the actual work. In your case, this work concludes with sending an email.

In a way, this is kind of like MediatR but explicitly going out of process with the on-disk queue and a separate process being your handler.

Comment: Thanks I'lve gone through some of your posts, but there is not much code. I'll I guess using hangfire for the durable jobs part will do the intended job ?

Comment: @DamienDoumer: Yes, [with caveats](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/02/asynchronous-messaging-5-miscellaneous-considerations.html#:~:text=mix%20and%20match.-,All%2DIn%2DOne,-And%20then%20there).

Comment: Thank you. Will try that out. I've come along another approach using System.Threading.Tasks.Channels to queue tasks to be run by the background service. I'll ive deeper into both approaches and see what's the most appropriate.

Comment: @DamienDoumer: Channels are in-memory queues, so they aren't a correct solution - assuming you always want the background work to be done.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'll stick to hang fire then.

Answer (score 1):

I would handle API calls that takes some time separately from calls that can be completed directly.

when I do API calls that takes time, I queue them up and process them on the backend.

a typical API call can look something like this:

```
POST http://api.example.com/orders HTTP/1.1
Host: api.example.com

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Fri, 5 Oct 2012 17:17:11 GMT
Content-Length: 123
Content-Type: application/json
Location: http://poll.example.com/orders/59cc233e-4068-4d4a-931d-cd5eb93f8c52.xml
ETag: "c180de84f951g8" 

{ uri: 'http://poll.example.com/orders/59cc233e-4068-4d4a-931d-cd5eb93f8c52.xml'}
```

the returned URL is a unique url where the client then can poll/query to get an idea about the status of the job.

When the client queries this URL, then it can look something like this:
[image]

and when it is later done, the result would be something like:
[image]

Where dataurl is a link to the result/report that the client then can download.

Comment: Thanks, please how do you queue them up? what comes to my mind is hangfire. but do you have a different way of doing this ?

Comment: That I imlplemented a custom queue solution for in the backend.. in Hangfire? I have no idea.. You dom't want to have HTTP requests that take minutes to complete, as the client might timeout for example....

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using Channels with background services in asp.net core to accomplish this,